# assigned value to dynamic array created in void function doesnt return the same value in main()

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem with dynamic arrays in C. My program was working perfectly, but I was asked to put the creation of dynamic array into a seperate void. I did it, and it still worked great, but then I had to assign a value to a certain point of the created array in void, and make it return the said value, however, what I get is a random value. The function works by sending a pointer and the lenght of required array into void, and then makes the pointer into a dynamic array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 255
void ieskom (int skaiciai[],int n, int *de, int *me, int *n1, int *n2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int nr1 = 0;
    int nr2 = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int temp1 = 0;
    int eile = 0;
    int eile1 = 0;
    int *did;
    did = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    if (did==NULL)
    {
        printf("Nepriskirta atminties.");
        exit(0);
    }
    int *maz;
    maz = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    if (maz==NULL)
    {
        printf("Nepriskirta atminties.");
        exit(0);
    }
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (skaiciai[i] < skaiciai[i+1])
        {
            did[j] = did[j] + 1;
            if (did[j] > temp)
            {
                eile = j;
                temp = did[j];
                nr1 = i+1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            did[j] = did[j] + 1;
            if (did[j] > temp)
            {
                eile = j;
                temp = did[j];
                nr1 = i+1;
            }
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (skaiciai[i] > skaiciai[i+1])
        {
            maz[j] = maz[j] + 1;
            if (maz[j] > temp1)
            {
                eile1 = j;
                temp1 = maz[j];
                nr2 = i+1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            maz[j] = maz[j] + 1;
            if (maz[j] > temp1)
            {
                eile1 = j;
                temp1 = maz[j];
                nr2 = i+1;
            }
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    *de = did[eile];
    *me = maz[eile1];
    *n1 = nr1;
    *n2 = nr2;
    free(did);
    free(maz);
}
/*int masyvas(x)
{
    int y;
    y = (int*)malloc(x*sizeof(int));
    return y;
}*/
void *masyvas (int *skaiciai, int n)
{
    *skaiciai = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    skaiciai[2] = 5;
    return skaiciai;
}
int main()
{
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int de = 0;
    int me = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int *skaiciai;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // skaiciai = masyvas(n); // naudojant int
    masyvas(&skaiciai, n);
    printf("2 = %d", skaiciai[2]);
    if (skaiciai==NULL)
    {
        printf("Nepriskirta atminties.");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (;i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &skaiciai[i]);
    }
    ieskom (skaiciai, n, &de, &me, &n1, &n2);
    if (de > me)
    {
        printf("Elementu numeriai:");
        printf(" %d", n1-de+1);
        printf(" %d\n", n1);
        printf("\nAtstumas tarp ju: %d", de-2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Elementu numeriai:");
        printf(" %d", n2-me+1);
        printf(" %d\n", n2);
        printf("\nAtstumas tarp ju: %d", me-2);
    }
    free(skaiciai);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in void masyvas and printf skaicia[2] - I assign a certain value to skaiciai[2], yet it prints a random one. How do I fix it?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers and explanations, it really helped me a lot! I know have solved my problem, and most importantly, I know why it was a problem in the first place.

Comment: The `masyvas` function is incorrect. You should get compiler errors about this. Pay attention to what your compiler is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer-to-pointer here and do not need to return anything.

```
void masyvas (int **skaiciai, int n)
{
    *skaiciai = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    (*skaiciai)[2] = 5;
}
```

When you declare `int *skaiciai`, the variable is a pointer to type int. `skaiciai` holds the address that points to an int. When you pass `&skaiciai`, you're passing the address of the address that points to an int. So because this is an address of an address, its a double pointer.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. 
Maybe you could explain why this way works and mine doesnt? If no, still thanks a lot! I will have to read about pointer-to-pointer passing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should translate variables and texts to english (your code lack of comments, this should apply to them too).

Next your `masyvas()` function returns a pointer to the allocated array (why void* ?!) but when you call it you don't get the returned value.

You have to choose: either you pass a pointer to your function (an array is a pointer, to if you want an array to be allocated from a function you have to pass a pointer to the pointer, so a int **), or you use the returned value.

Allocating with returned value:

```
// this function allocates a int* tab of size n and set one value
int *allocate_tab(int n) {
  int *tmp;
  tmp = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    return(NULL); // failed
  }
  tmp[2] = 5;
  return(tmp);
}
// in main (or other function)
int *mytab;

mytab = alloc_tab(45);
```

Allocating by passing a pointer to the array:

```
void alloc_tab(int **tab, int n) {
  *tab = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  if (*tab == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  (*tab)[2] = 5;
}
// in main (or other)
int *mytab;
alloc_tab(&mytab, 45);
```

If you can't understand this stuff I guess you should read more about memory, allocation and pointers.

Comment: Thanks! We just started pointers in university, so I dont really understand them well yet, I guess ill have to do some more reading..
Oh and I had it done with int function, but then was asked to change it into void for whatever reason.

Comment: A pointer is a "target" to a place in memory. An array is a pointer to the 1st element of a sequence in memory. Allocating consists in asking for a range of memory of requested size, and returns the pointer to the 1st element of this range. So a function that allocates something  have to get at last a pointer to this "1st element". And in C only values are passed. So to get a pointer you have 2 solutions: 1. return a pointer, and get it into a pointer (here a int*), or pass a "pointer to the pointer" (the &mytab in my example) so that the function knows where to put the pointer (in your int*).